# Number of Solutions for $p^2 - q^2$ = n?

Tags: number-theory, quadratics

Number of Solutions for $p^2 - q^2 = n$? how do I find it? It was asked in aptitude test of a company , couldn't figure it out. What is the answer of it?

Edit:

once again i faced similar question for :$p^2 - q^2 = 388$

**options : 1 , 2 , 3 , More than 3.**

what is answer ?

Comment: Please provide more details as to what $p,q,n$ are.

Comment: I don't have a copy of that question right now :(. I only remember this part. Can you solve using assumptions?

Comment: for prime n, there exists only one such (p,q). For composite n, there may be multiple ways to write it

Comment: so answer varies and depends on n if n is not prime , right? @Lelouch

Comment: check the edit guys

Comment: Don't forget the "same parity" part. Since $388 = 2^2\cdot 97$ is even, both factors must be even, and we get $$\frac{p-q}{2}\cdot \frac{p+q}{2} = 97.$$

Comment: Are $p$ and $q$ intended to be prime? because that is a different answer... that's not available as an option.

Comment: @Joffan only 98 and 96 satisfies this..and no there is no prime restriction on p and q..only integral solution It should be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$n = p^2 - q^2 = (p+q)(p-q)$  So every such decomposition gives you a factorization and vice versa.

However there is a gotcha.  If only one of $p+q$ and $p-q$ is odd, then $p$ is not an integer.  So it is the number of factors where the parity of the two factors is the same.

Given the prime factorization of $n$ it is not hard to figure out how many such factorizations exist.

Comment: Would it be more accurate to say that the number of solutions is the number of _two factor factorizations_ where the parity of the two factors is the same?

Comment: If n is prime ..is there only one pair of p and q as Lelouch said?

Comment: @minigeek, yes. for a prime p, it can only be decomposed in one way as $p=((p+1)/2)^2-((p-1)/2)^2$. For example 7=4^2-3^2.

Comment: @browngreen That is a perfectly accurate summation.

Comment: check the edit please

Comment: @minigeek Looks good.

Comment: @btilly ans is 1. Only one pair satisfies. 98 and 96

Comment: @minigeek When I answered, the specific number had not been specified.  So I was giving a general answer about how to approach it.

Comment: @btilly yeah got it later..thanx :)

Answer (score -1):

Write the given equation as $p^2-q^2=388$.

Now prime factorize R.H.S.
[Click this to view the entire solution.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6TPP.jpg)